# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Service while compiling nest project

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Getting below error while compiling the below code:
I am new to nestjs and this is the attached sample application code.
I tried replacing UsersService in module.ts with UsersModule as well but it didn't work. What am i doing wrong ?

```
 [Nest] 19960 - 10/19/2020, 11:42:09 PM [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 19960 - 10/19/2020, 11:42:09 PM [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +25ms
[Nest] 19960 - 10/19/2020, 11:42:09 PM [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 19960 - 10/19/2020, 11:42:09 PM [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, JwtService). Please make sure that the argument UsersService at index [0] is available in the AuthService context.

Potential solutions:

If UsersService is a provider, is it part of the current AuthService?
If UsersService is exported from a separate @module, is that module imported within AuthService?
@module({
imports: [ /* the Module containing UsersService */ ]
})
```

Repoistory : https://github.com/richakhetan/task-manager-nest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modules were not properly structured. I removed the code causing circular dependency from the modules and created a new module creating a clear structure.

Detailed Code can be found in the repository.
Repository : https://github.com/richakhetan/task-manager-nest

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency between the `AuthModule` and `UserModule` **and** between the `UserService` and `AuthService`. To resolve this, on both the modules and the services you need to use a `forwardRef`. Generally, this would just look like

```js
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => UserModule)],
  providers: [AuthService],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

```js
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => AuthModule)],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => UserService)) private readonly userService: UserService) {}
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  cosntructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => AuthService) private readonly authService: AuthService) {}
}
```

### Edit

Forgot to add the `exports` property

Comment: Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (UserModel, ?). Please make sure that the argument AuthService at index [1] is available in the UsersModule 
context.

Potential solutions:
- If AuthService is a provider, is it part of the current UsersModule?
- If AuthService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UsersModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing AuthService */ ]
  })

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot the `exports`

Comment: I have updated the repository as well. If that could give more context

Comment: In your repository, you have `forwardRef(() => AuthService` in an `imports` array. Services **never** go in the `imports` array.